# Javascript: each function value dynamic title

Tags: json, jquery, each, key-value, dynamically-generated

I am trying to use following code:

```
var list_id = "Cust";
var page_id = "SubPageCust";
var show = "Company";
$.ajax({            

    url: "sap.php",
    dataType: "json",
    type: "POST",
    success: function(data) {
                   var output = '';
                   $('#' + list_id).empty(); 
                   var value1 = "value." + show;
                   $.each(data, function(index, value){

                         output += '<li><a href="#' + value.show
                         +'" data-transition="slide">' + value.show + '</a></li>';

                   });  
    $('#' + list_id).append(output).listview('refresh');
```

The JSON title is Company:Company. Has anyone an idea how to use the value.title dynamically?

Regards

Comment: Got it: var val = "value." + show; => change value.show to eval(val)